# Error XDG0066 System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.XamlRoot Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.get_XamlRoot()'

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics) but I get an error on **line**:

`<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">`

The **error** is:

`XDG0066    System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.XamlRoot Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.get_XamlRoot()'.`

**ConvertPage.xaml:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.ConvertPage.ConvertPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">  <--- line with error

        </controls:DataGrid>


    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**ConvertPage.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace MyApp.ConvertPage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class ConvertPage : Page
    {
        public ConvertPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp **v7.1.2**

Target: **Universal Windows**

Min and Target Version: **17763**

[image]

[image]

Comment: When does this exception happen? When you navigate to the ConvertPage or it happens as soon as you build the project?  I failed to reproduce this issue in a blank UWP project. Could you reproduce this issue in another project?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I added a screen capture to the question. It seems that it happens after building the project.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I also added a print screen with the other errors I get. Don't know what they mean but it might be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked this and I could reproduce this issue. The issue is caused by the **Min and Target Version**. When adding the nuget package into the project, it contains a warning saying `Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.18362.0 (current project is 17763)`.

Please change the Min and Target Version of your project to 18362 or higher and run your app again. It should solve the issue.

Comment: I didn't have version 18362 of win 10 SDK in the dropdown. The solution was to install Visual Studio Community 2019 (I had 2017) which came with 18362 version and one newer. Thanks for your time Roy.